# How to disable serial console during bootup

Tags: linux, serial-port, linux-device-driver, upstart

I have stopped ttyS0 (initctl stop serial DEV=ttyS0). The ttyS0 process stops for the session but reappears post to reboot, I want to disable ttyS0 at boot as it throws errors like:

```
Feb 19 20:19:42 sdm2 init: serial (ttyS0) main process (608881) terminated with status 1
Feb 19 20:19:42 sdm2 init: serial (ttyS0) main process ended, respawning
Feb 19 20:19:42 sdm2 init: initLogger main process (608986) terminated with status 1
```

I couldnt find any /etc/init/ttyS0.conf but serial.conf exists.

I searched for 'respawn' in an attempt to turn it OFF, but I found 'respawn' in serial.conf.

```
instance $DEV
respawn
pre-start exec /sbin/securetty $DEV 
./init/serial.conf-33-exec /sbin/agetty /dev/$DEV $SPEED vt100-nav
```

Though /etc/ttyS0.conf doesnt exists,but  I used 'echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/ttyS0.override' to stop the ttyS0 at boot time.

-Also I removed ttyS0 from securetty.

-There is no mention of ttyS0 in inittab file.

-In grub.conf I have two console entries tty0 and console=ttyS0,115200 as well.

-/dev/ttyS0 exists but /etc/init/ttyS0.conf does nt.

Could anyone assist in stopping ttyS0 after reboot.

Comment: Well you've told the kernel to use ttyS0 as a console, so it's not too surprising you are seeing log messages on the serial port. Get rid of `console=ttyS0,11500` from the kernel command line in grub.conf.

Comment: Try changing to console=quiet and make sure this change is saved. However, this might not be exactly what you want. Better show your grub.conf here in full, so people don't have to guess..